# Get all values that match a condition over entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Given a very large DataFrame with many columns and millions of rows, how would one extract a set of all values that match a given condition. For my use case, the condition is the value is in parentheses i.e., `'(example)'` would be a value that should match the condition, but `'(example'` shouldn't.

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '(2)', '3', '(4', '(5)'], 'B':['a', 'b', '(c)', 'd', 'e']})
```

Which gives:

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   (2) b
2   3   (c)
3   (4  d
4   (5) e
```

Desired result:

```
{'(2)', '(5)', '(c)'}
```

The emphasis is on the scale of the DataFrame, the efficiency of the solution is the key metric here.

Comment: What about `(1))`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be a value in my data but no, it shouldn't match `(1))`. For robustness this should be taken into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need match only values `()` and not `())` or `(()` or `something()anything` use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for start of strings, `\(.*\)` for any values in `()` and `$` for end of string:

```
s = df.stack()
out = set(s[s.str.contains('^\(.*\)$')])
print (out)
{'(5)', '(2)', '(c)'}
```

Comment: `match` would be preferred to `contains` in this case at it directly matches from the beginning (thus no need for the `^`)

Comment: @mozway - ya, I prefer it, because more readable

Answer (score 1):

You can unstack to make your data 1D, filter using the `'\(.*\)'` regex that matches anything surrounded by parentheses, and transform to set:

```
s = df.unstack()
set(s[s.str.match('\(.*\)')])
```

output:

```
{'(2)', '(5)', '(c)'}
```

*NB. if you need to ensure that the parentheses are in the extremities, use `'\(.*\)$'` as regex*